# SQL Server : combine two rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a query which will display the following result

FROM

```
  ID      Contract#          Market
   1       123kjs             40010
   1       123kjs             40011
   2       121kjs             40098
   2       121kjs             40099
```

TO

```
  ID      Contract#          Market
   1       123kjs             40010,40011
   2       121kjs             40098,40099
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I been trying if statement on excel.. Thought it would be easier to write sql query.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: Can you please **explain** what you're trying to achieve? Just dumping two piles of data on us and letting us figure it out (or *guessing it*) is not really a good strategy....

Comment: Hey Marc_c wht im trying to achieve looks pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this query, I use GROUP_CONCAT to turn column fields into 1 row field.

Also notice that you should rename the `FROM clause` with the name of your table.

```
 SELECT ID,Contract#, GROUP_CONCAT(Market SEPARATOR ',') 
    FROM nameOfThatTable GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I used `PIVOT` to solve it.

```
  SELECT 
         ID,
         Contract#,
         ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar,[40010]) + ',' + CONVERT(varchar,[40011]),
         CONVERT(varchar,[40098]) + ',' + CONVERT(varchar,[40099])) AS Market FROM
  ( SELECT * FROM ContractTable) AS A
  PIVOT(MIN(Market) FOR Market IN ([40010],[40011],[40098],[40099])) AS PVT
  ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `', ' + CAST(Market AS VARCHAR(30))` in sub-query and join `Id` and `Contract#` of sub-query with outer query to get values of `Market` as **Comma Separated Values** for each `Id` and `Contract#`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,Contract#,
SUBSTRING(
         (SELECT  ', ' + CAST(Market AS VARCHAR(30))
         FROM #TEMP T1
         WHERE T2.Id=T1.Id AND T2.Contract#=T1.Contract#             
         FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) Market
FROM #TEMP T2
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281086/rows-to-comma-separated-values) to view result**

**Note

.........**
If you want to get **CSV** values for `Id` only, remove `T2.Contract#=T1.Contract#`  from sub-query.

Comment: Did u get the output? Please reply @Bibek Shrestha

Comment: I tend to use `STUFF(<expression>, 1, 2, '')` instead of `SUBSTRING(<expression, 2, <some large number>)` as it avoids a bug when the expression gets larger than the arbitrarily chosen large number. But this is the idiomatic way.